# Radix Sort C++ Not masking bits

Tags: c++, data-structures, radix-sort

I have an queue and and an array of queues. `buckets` is the the array and `collector` is the queue. `pass` is an integer that saves which pass it is. I have a method that returns to me the contains of the first cell of the queue called `peek()`. `shiftOne()` is a method that moves the head of one queue to the tail of another.

Now this code does not work for me

```
bucket[((collector.peek()>>(pass * 8)) &0xFF)].shiftOne(collector);
```

I have gone step by step and it turn out I am not masking the bits properly. I can shift them but that is about it. So I will try to access element 102 for an 10 element array. What am I doing wrong? I know `peek()` and `shiftOne()` because I can sort using powers and modulus.

Comment: The `8` and `0xFF` are consisent with using a radix-256 sort, in which case your arrays should be 256 elements (and accessing element 102 is just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing radix-10 with radix-2.

Bit shifting is division by 2, so for example: `102 >> 1` = `102 / 2` = 51.

Similarly: `102 >> 8` = `102 / 2^8` = `102 / 256` = 0 (in `int` terms).

The code `(i >> 8) & 0xFF` for example is used to extract the content of **the second byte** of the given `i` value.

For your case - stick with divisions by 10 with modulus.

Comment: Actually looks like he's confusion radix-256 with radix-10 as he's shifting 8 bits at a time.